# Django - How do I can have a big initialization required for a view (APIView)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a simple APIView:

```
class MyView(APIView):
    symspell = Symspell()

    def post(self, request):
        res = self.symspell.do_something()
        return res
```

Here's my issue: the constructor of my class Symspell required something like 30s to run. So when i run or do anything with my app really (like ./manage.py migrate) it adds 30s to the runtime.
So my questions would be:

- is there a better way to do this ? (use a class with a long constructor in a view)
- can i only construct this view when i'm ONLY running the server and not doing other operations like migrations ?
- can i use the same class in several views ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: can you not use `@staticmethod` for `do_something` so you dont need to initialize?

Answer (score 2):

> is there a better way to do this ? (use a class with a long constructor in a view)

I don't think so, although I've never seen a constructor this heavy, so don't consider me an authority on this.

> can i only construct this view when i'm ONLY running the server and not doing other operations like migrations ?

This is doable if you run the constructor inside the `initial()` function of the `APIView`.

> can i use the same class in several views ?

I think you mean use the same *object* in several views? If so, you can implement the class as a **singleton** to avoid rerunning the constructor each time.